# What is the Chinese term for a DGEN or Degen Gambler

Tags: simplified-characters, classical-chinese

What is the Chinese term for a DGEN gambler or a Degen Gambler, this phrase is usually used not in a bad way by pro gamblers who considers themselves or others DGEN/Degen gamblers as they thrive and live on gambling.

How would this be translated into Chinese in a way that it does not mean Degenerate which is considered a very bad word in itself.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to gather a euphemism for Degen Gambler in Chinese. No best words/phrases I figure. 职业扑克玩家 (Professional Pokerist) is the best one I can get.

hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

**赌棍** is the best you're gonna get.

There are very few translations of *DGEN* -or- *Degen*. The only one I came across was on [扑克人](http://www.pokerren.com/a/56) which says:

> **堕落故事**
>
> 译注：原帖标题为“Degen Stories”。Degen是Degenrate的缩写，意思是“堕落的”、“落魄的”、“穷困潦倒的”。Degen Stories差不多就是“很衰的事情”、“很背的事情”的意思（还有一点no zuo no die的味道）。

Degen here is translated as:

- 堕落 = worsening of morals
- 落魄 = to be down on one's luck
- 穷困潦倒 = to be down and out

These are all quite negative and mean exactly what you didn't want them to mean: **degenerate**.

The negative meaning of *DGEN* -or- *Degen* does seem to be pretty overwhelming in English as well, but obviously not exclusively, so our above translations are all out.

CC-CEDICT translates **[赌棍](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E8%B5%8C%E6%A3%8D)** as:

> 1 hardened gambler
>
> 2 professional gambler

**现代汉语大词典** says:

> 沉溺于赌博，并以此为生的人

which very roughly translates as *an obsessive gambler, who does it for a living*.

But it can also refer to any obsessive gambler in general.

I think this is the closest you'll get for what you want to express.

**赌徒** could also work but this is more of a derogatory term for a *hobby* gambler.

**赌神** could also work, borrowing from the movie, a word that literally means *gambling god* but could refer to anyone who is masterful at gambling.

Comment: Well, 赌棍 does not appear positive at all. 赌棍 sounds even a bit worse than 赌徒.

Answer (score 1):

> Definition of 'Degen Gambler'
>
> http://pokerterms.com/degenerate.html
>
> *A personality type, common amongst poker players, that is typified by an abundance of self-destructive behavior.*
>
> *Common Degen Habits*
>
> *There are a variety of "degenerate behavior" patterns that poker players have been known to embrace. They include, but are not limited to:*
>
> - *Pit gambling*
> - *Drug use*
> - *Excessive spending*
> - *Sports betting*
> - *Hookers and strippers*

I would translate Degen Gambler as **病態賭徒** (sick/ symptomatic gambler)

'Degen' stands for 'degenerate'

The thing that is degenerating in a degen Gambler is his mental health, which causes all kinds of symptoms in the forms of destructive behaviors.

When someone's mental health degenerates to a certain point, his behaviors will become symptomatic of that mental illness.

When we say someone is a 病態賭徒, it means gambling has took over of his life, and he is on the path of self destruct. At this point, he really need professional help from psychology doctor.

> Matt Douhan wrote:
>
> *This phrase is usually used not in a bad way by pro gamblers who considers themselves or others DGEN/Degen gamblers as they thrive and live on gambling.*

Obviously a professional gambler would not consider himself sick. A professional gambler calling himself 'degen gambler' or 'sick gambler' (病態賭徒) is akin to a scientist calling himself 'mad scientist' (瘋狂科學家) to express how devoted he is to his endeavor.

A professional gambler may consider his devotion to gambling is so deep, it qualifies as a sickness-- 'sick gambler' (病態賭徒).

Borrowing the mad scientist example, 'degen gambler' may even be translated as '**瘋狂玩家**' (mad player)

Comment: I understand that degenerate part but amongst pro gamblers like myself we don't consider degen to be such a negative meaning as the word itself implies meaning degen is almost a positive version of degenerate

Comment: See the  comment I added at the bottom of my post.

Comment: I see the update to your answer but how to reflect that in Chinese characters translation ?

Comment: A professional  gambler may consider his devotion to gambling is so deep, it qualifies as a sickness-- 'sick gambler' (病態賭徒)

Comment: looks like we need create one :)